# NSTimeInterval since1970 to NSDate

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

I have the following code:

```
-(void)setDate:(double)dateInterval {
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)dateInterval];
    NSLog(@"NSDate-Result: %@", [date description]);

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS"];

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"String-Result: %@", dateString);

    date_label.text = dateString;
}
```

in `NSDate` the Date is correct, but the converted string isn't correct anymore.

Results:

> 2012-08-03 10:58:40.469 iSkizzenaufmass[4148:c07] NSDate-Result:
>   2012-08-03 08:08:35 +0000 2012-08-03 10:58:40.471
>   iSkizzenaufmass[4148:c07] String-Result: 2012-08-216 10:08:48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS` instead of -DD (DD is day of the year)

EDIT: changed YYYY to yyyy as YYYY is week based year and could differ from current year (see link below for all opts)

- http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns